# RSolve[] gives error RSolve::litarg when solving demo equations from the official documentation

Tags: equation-solving, documentation, difference-equations

The [official documentation of RSolve[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html#433406314) (specifically, in the fifth paragraph of the seciton "Details and Options") states that:

> The specification a∈Vectors[m] or a∈Matrices[{m,p}] can be used to indicate that the dependent variable a is a vector-valued or a matrix-valued variable, respectively.

Moreover,There are two subsequent working examples on this there:

[image]

[image]

However, when I was running those two examples above on my PC, MMA gives me errors RSolve::litarg, outputting the command input untouched:

```
a = {{n, 1}, {1, 0}};
RSolve[x[n + 1] == a . x[n], Element[x[n], Vectors[2]], n]
```

[image]
[image]

Things are similar when I was running the second example:

```
a = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};
x0 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
sol = RSolve[{x[n + 1] == a . x[n], x[0] == x0}, 
   Element[x[n], Matrices[{2, 2}]], n];
x[n] /. sol[[1]] // MatrixForm
```

I was somewhat surprised to find this since I run the identical code  pasted from the working example in the official documentation,where the specific code is displayed working fine.

Any idea on why the case happens and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Both examples work for me in version 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: @cvgmt, The code can be copied from the online documentation conveniently. To make it more convenient, I have posted the code as you wish.

Comment: @user64494. My pc is also a Win 10 but with the MMA version 12.3.1. I have no ideal if it is an issue caused by the version since there is no sign of recent update in the online documentation. The last update indicated there is "Updated in 2008 (7.0)".

Comment: The documentation shipped with V12.3 and also available [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12.3/ref/RSolve.html) does NOT contain this example. There must have been an update after V12.3, even if the current online documentation lists "Updated in 2008 (7.0)" as the last update as you say.

Comment: @user293787. I see. I have also checked the built-in documentation in my V12.3 and it is true there does NOT contain those examples. If it is the case, MMA seems to have some oversight here on their project documentation. It is their duty to at least make their real-time online documentation faithfully record the most recent update over those Core Kernel Functions and remind users so there.

Comment: @AlbertLew I recommend that you report this to wolfram support as a potential need to improve the documentation.

Comment: The example is in my V13.1 documentation and works without giving any error messages. (Mac M1)